# Show Interstitial Ad after splash screen in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing an application in react native one of the requirements of the application in showing an interstitial ad when starting the application before it loads any component, this due to the policies of admob google, otherwise it brings penalties in the ads.

I've been trying in several ways first to put a in componentDidMount and in the constructor the react-native-admob code for interstitial, however the ad likewise takes time to load causing the component (screen) to load completely , which should not be allowed until the ad loads and closes.

Should the ad be added natively (native code for android) or is there any other way to place that ad

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, because there are politics of Google Admob

you can read all the documentation

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6066980?hl=es&ref_topic=2936214
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362